# Maps between Power Sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition, problem-solving

Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a map and let $X \subseteq A$ and $Y \subseteq B$ Then by definition, we have the following two sets:

> The **image of $X$**, which is the set $f(X)=$ { $b\in B$ | $b = f(x)$ for some $x \in X$}.
>
> The **inverse image of $Y$**, which is the set $f^{-1}(Y)=$ { $a \in A$ | $f(a) \in Y$}.

I read that we can think of the map $f$ as **inducing the maps** $f_*: \mathcal{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)$ and $f^*: \mathcal{P}(B) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$. But I’m not really seeing how I can use this maps.

My doubt arose from the following problem (from a book about fundamentals) which I’m still working on but (yet) without success:

> Let $f,g: A \rightarrow B$ be maps. Think of these maps as inducing maps $f_*,g_*: \mathcal{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)$, and maps $f^*,g^*: \mathcal{P}(B) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$. Show that $f_* = g_*$ iff $f^* = g^*$ iff $f=g$.

I would really appreciate if someone could:

1. Explain what these maps $f_*,g_*$ and $f^*,g^*$ are, what is the “motivation”/relation between the original maps $f,g$ And how do they relate with the concepts of image and inverse image.
2. I’m not yet looking for the solution for this problem, but still I would like to get some advices about “what should I do” or “where should I start”.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f=g$ and $X\subset A$, then$$f_*(X)=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}=\{g(x)\mid x\in X\}=g_*(X).$$And if $f\ne g$, take some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)\ne g(a)$. Then $f_*(\{a\})\ne g_*(\{a\})$, since $f_*(\{a\})=\{f(a)\}$ and $g_*(\{a\})=\{g(a)\}$.

So, I have proved that $f=g\iff f_*=g_*$.

Can you prove now that $f=g\iff f^*=g^*$?

Comment: If $f=g$ and $Y \subseteq B$, then $f^*(Y)=$ {$a \in A$ | $f(a) \in Y$}. Since $f(a) = g(a)$ for all $a \in A$, then {$a \in A$ | $f(a) \in Y$} = {$a \in A$ | $g(a) \in Y$} = $g^*(Y)$. Hence $f^*(Y)=g^*(Y)$. If we had the case $f \neq g$, following the same argument in your answer it yield that the maps $f^*$ and $g^*$ are different. Is that it? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: One question @JoséCarlosSantos: So, if $f \neq g$ then there must be $b \in B$ such that $f^{-1}(b) \neq g^{-1}(b)$. Hence we have that $f^*(\{b\})=\{f^*(b)\}$, $g^*(\{b\})=\{g^*(b)\}$ and $f^*(\{b\}) \neq g^*(\{b\})$. Therefore $f^* \neq g^*$?

Comment: I would say that if $f \neq g$ then there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) \neq g(a)$. Let $a_0$ be that element. Since $f(a_0) \neq g(a_0)$, then either $a_0 \in f^*(\{f(a_0)\})$ and $a_0 \notin g^*(\{f(a_0)\})$, or $a_0 \notin f^*(\{f(a_0)\})$ and $a_0 \in g^*(\{f(a_0)\})$. The former yields $f^*(\{f(a_0)\}) \not\subseteq g^*(\{f(a_0)\})$, the latter yields $g^*(\{f(a_0)\}) \not\subseteq f^*(\{f(a_0)\})$. In both cases, we conclude that $f^*(\{f(a_0)\}) \neq g^*(\{f(a_0)\})$. Therefore $f^* \neq g^*$. Confirm @JoséCarlosSantos ?

Comment: Yes, I confirm.